# Creating a layout of the city

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, cities

I want to create a layout for the city in my story(like streets, lakes, buildings etc..) or maybe we can call it town planning. I have the list of all the things that exist but I'm unable to keep them at right places. Is there any way I can do it online?
My question is, is there any software or online website that allows me to create a layout. Using which I can name the places, resize them and create a graphical representation of what I want.

Comment: Have you considered lasting it out in Minecraft?

Comment: @pojo-guy Minecraft is a sandbox, it won't help with the logical placement of things in a city.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! Please have a look at the [Tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)! If you want to have a functional city, you can either a) think about historical growth , e.g. what would be built first, where would the city expand over time ect. or b) what is the reason the city has been founded there, e.g. as a commercial center, as a production location, as a military fort etc. This could ease the planning quite a bit.

Comment: Welcome Vishal, if you are looking for a resource, please clarify exactly what you need the software to be able to do.  Check out the [help] and [tour] to get familiar with the site.  I am going to put this question on hold so we can get details from you before more people answer.

Comment: You may also find this answer useful:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/how-can-i-ensure-my-cities-dont-all-look-the-same/2900#2900

Comment: At this point I think it becomes a duplicate rather than unclear. We have a fair number of questions about mapping tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a lot of mapmaker software, and they're not really helpful if you don't already have a layout ready. Those software help you draw the map, give it a certain look that fits any type of world, but they don't help you place things logically.

I'd recommend that you look at existing maps of real or imaginary places, though I'd suggest focusing more on real places, to see how everything shapes up and how various things are placed.

For example: how a castle is built on top of a hill, then the church is either built nearby or on the other side of the river, so the monks can enjoy peace while not being too far from the local lord. Then, as the city grows, it will extend from the castle to the river because commerce is done mainly via the river, thus the mill is constructed right next to the river, and so on.

More technological or high-tech world allow more flexibility, but there are still some rules to follow.

If you're really completely stuck, I'd suggest trying city building games like Sim City or Cities Skylines. That would teach you a few things about how cities need to be organized, albeit you can only build modern-day cities with those games. But it should still help you with your city and the landscape around it.

Comment: Generally you should work with a querent before answering if you know the question is too vague/broad

Answer (score 0):

There's [inkarnate](https://inkarnate.com/). It allows you to create maps. Your answer is honestly a bit vague, if this isn't what you're looking for, though. You should add more details. Personally, I recommend using grid paper irl. It allows you to be a little more flexible and have better control over manipulating your layout.

Comment: Welcome Sora.  Generally you should work with a querent before answering if you know the question is too vague/broad.  Check out the [help] and [tour] for more info.

Comment: My apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: No worries Sora.  It takes time to get used to how things are done around here :)